# Select multiples rows with Where clause in an attribute that forms the key

Tags: sql, database

I have a SQL table which key is formed by the combination of three attributes. I want to SELECT all the rows which have, for example, 2 as a value in the column 'id'. But that column is part of the key, so the return is the last row that gathers that condition. I want all the rows.

I hope to be clear with my question.

Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE Prestar
(
    emailUser varchar(30),
    idLibro integer,
    fechaHora datetime,
    fechaFin date,
    PRIMARY KEY(emailUser, idLibro, fechaHora),
    FOREIGN KEY(emailUser) REFERENCES User(email),
    FOREIGN KEY(idLibro) REFERENCES Book(id)
)
```

The select I am pretending:

```
SELECT emailUser 
FROM Prestar 
WHERE idLibro = ?;
```

Data in the database is:

[image]

The result is the last row, but I want all which have idLibro=2.

Comment: sample data and desired output will make your question even more clear

Comment: Hi - please update your question with 1) sample data for your table 2) the result you want to achieve used this data 3) the SQL you’ve managed to write so far 4) a clear explanation of the precise issue you are facing. All code, data etc should be editable text formatted appropriately (data as tables, code as code)

Comment: The question isn't clear. Could you provide the input data, query you tried, actual result and desired result?

Comment: Every database I know would - for `WHERE idLibro =2` - return **all** rows whose idLibro column value equals 2, not only the last row. Which database do you use? Any way you could create fiddle which illustrates what you're saying?

Comment: Are you using the query within a business class? Possibly you are fetching one row at the time but the query is returning more rows than you are fetching

Comment: `the return is the last row that gathers that condition.` << is this on application or dbms?